# Jira project components

Tags: components, project, jira

We have two groups of developers, server side and client side with project components defined serverside and client side. If a user creates a serverside task I would like the assignee drop down box show only the server side group and vice versa. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be creating two separate JIRA projects for the two components and giving developers permissions to the appropriate project.

Answer (score 0):

You could create two custom drop-downs and make them visible to only the respective user group (such as serverside-group and clientside-group).